# Error accessing an array's value by it's index?

Tags: ruby

Trying to sum up all the numbers in an array. *Example 10 + 20 + 30 should be 60.*

```
def sum *arr
  i=0
  total=0
  while i <= arr.count
    total += arr[i]
    i+=1
  end
  total
end

puts sum(10,20,30)
```

Why am I getting this error. This code looks like it should work to me. What am I doing wrong? Why wont it let me access the array value by it's index?

```
p8.rb:23:in `+': nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
        from p8.rb:23:in `sum'
        from p8.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and learn about how `arr.inject(:+)` works.

Comment: or just user ```arr.sum``` if you're on rails

Comment: Thanks, I've used in `inject` and `reduce` and the like, but I'm still struggling to comprehend why the above code returns an error. Is it something internally with Ruby?

Comment: This code would fail in just about any language since you are going through the loop `count+1` times. Nothing to do with Ruby. Count `0`, `1`, ..., `count`. Starting from `0`, that's `count+1` times. Your array has only `count` elements. If this were in C, you'd be getting a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
while i <= arr.count
```

to

```
while i < arr.count
```

`arr[arr.count]` is always out of bounds.

---

Fyi a shorter way to write `sum` is:

```
def sum *arr
  arr.inject(:+)
end
```

Comment: To expand on this: an array of length N has its elements numbered from 0 through N-1.  For instance, in a 10-element array, the elements are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, and 9.  There is no element number 10.  (There would be if the numbering started with 1 instead of 0).

Comment: How the hell does that work? I could of swore I tried that too. Now I'm struggling to understand how it's "out of bounds"

Comment: @feed_me_code In your example, valid values for `i` are `0,1,2`. `arr.count` is 3.

Comment: Right so in the first iteration you would get `while 0 <= 3` I don't understand how that is "out of bounds".  Am I losing my mind? Doesn't `<=` mean "less than or equal to"? Thanks for the answer, but I'm still not quite understanding how that change makes a difference.

Comment: @feed_me_code It goes out of bounds when `i==3`. Try putting a `puts i` in the loop to see for yourself. P.s. Nice avatar image! :)

Comment: @Matt I understand now. I did `puts i` and then I did `return total if i == arr.count` I didn't realize what you meant was that `arr[3]` doesn't exist which makes it go out of bounds. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You want the loop to stop after `i`==2, not 3.  There is no element `[3]` in the array.  The `length` is 3 because there are three elements: `[0]`, `[1]`, and `[2]`.  There is no `[3]`.

Answer (score 1):

Matt's answer gives you the canonical Ruby way to sum, using inject. But if you're not ready to learn inject, at least save yourself the trouble of manually keeping track of array indexes (where your actual problem lies!) by using #each to iterate through the array like so:

```
def sum *arr
  total = 0
  arr.each do |x|
    total += x
  end
  total
end

puts sum(10,20,30) # => 60
```

Answer (score 0):

Matt's answer is both slick and correct, but you hit the error because ruby zero indexes arrays.  So if you changed the count condition

`while i <= arr.count - 1`

your error would go away